# Check if template page exists

Tags: templates

Is there a way to check if a template page exists?

When we embed pages we do it like this

```
{embed="foo/bar"}
```

I was thinking if it was possible to do something like this

```
{if {template_exists path="some/path"}}
  PAGE EXISTS
{if:else}
  PAGE DOES NOT EXISTS
{/if}
```

Comment: Why would there be a conditional if a template existed or not? Could you give an example?

Comment: Could you please give us more information or mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I created a plugin to help if you want. 
   http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/if-template-exists

You can do so with the query module (keep in mind your database prefixes may be different than "exp_"):

```
{query sql="SELECT 
                exp_templates.template_id
                FROM `exp_templates`
                LEFT JOIN `exp_template_groups`
                   ON exp_template_groups.group_id = exp_templates.group_id
                WHERE exp_template_groups.group_name = 'foo'
                   AND exp_templates.template_name = 'bar'
                limit=1"}

    [code if template exists]

    {if no_results} [code if template does not exist]{/if}
{/query}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin:

If Template Exists

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/if-template-exists